# Standard Deviation of pre/post test scores

Tags: standard-deviation

I have a problem that I need help with, please! 
I have results of a pre/post test and I was asked to find the standard deviation for that particular question.
Here is what the output looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zftcM.png)

30 users filled out the test and they either got it correct, or they got it incorrect.

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve this. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This [website](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html) has a good simple definition on how to calculate the standard deviation.